# Assign value to column with reference, using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem assigning a value to an entity that has a reference. I get the intellisense and all but I get a null-reference exception when I try to assign it to the object passed into the function that saves to database.

```
        public ActionResult BookingViewEdit([Bind(Include = "BookingViewID,Enabled,ObjectLimit,RSSenabled")]BookingView bv, int selCustomers)
    {
        bv.Customers.CustomerID = selCustomers;

        _bvs.SaveBookingView(bv);
```

Whats needed to do to assign the value for CustomerID? the FK-key is in the "BookingView"-table, and if I just hit "bv." there is no CustomerID there.

Thanks in advance

/M

Comment: Is the BookingView object you are assigning to new or has it already been persisted to the database at least once?   Is the relationship between BookingView and Customer one booking view to many customers or what?  Providing the basics of the data model seems like it would be valuable here (are any foreign keys nullable, etc.).

Comment: They are not nullable, each "BookingView" has to have a "CustomerID" to it, non-nullable FK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "Customers" actually a single Customer, not a list?

In that case, you could do something like:

```
bv.CustomerReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("MyEntities.Customers", "CustomerId", selCustomers);
```

Obviously, replace "MyEntities.Customers" with the actual entity context and entity set names.

I'll add that it's *extremely* confusing to use plural argument/property names for single objects.

Comment: In my entity-diagram there are no plurals. So the class there is called Customer

Comment: The class should be Customer (as you have it). The entity set name should be Customers. The selCustomers argument should be selCustomer (or, better per FxCop rules, selectedCustomer). bv.Customers should be bv.Customer